# UIModalPresentationFormSheet not an option for me iPad app 4.2?

Tags: ipad, ios4

I am trying to use UIModalPresentationFormSheet in my Ipad app but it does not come up as a valid choice in intellisense and I think it should.  I recently downloaded a new version of xCode and it seems to only have 4.2 and not 3.2 SDK - is this my problem?

Here is my code that I want to run but it crashes:

```
SignatureViewController *targetController = [[SignatureViewController alloc] init];
targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:targetController animated:YES];
```

Seems simple enough.

EDIT: Here is the crash report:

```
-[PreviewOrderViewController signOrder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ec75f0
2010-11-26 19:30:48.885 RepZioCoreData[37642:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PreviewOrderViewController signOrder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ec75f0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0132cbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014815c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0132e6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0129e366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0129df22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x003a8a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x004371b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00439647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x004381f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x003cd0d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x003ae37a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x003b3732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x01a22a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x01a22abd PurpleEventSignalCallback + 42
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0130e01f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0126c28b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0126b786 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0126b240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0126b161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x01a21268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x01a2132d GSEventRun + 115
    21  UIKit                               0x003b742e UIApplicationMain + 1160
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[PreviewOrderViewController signOrder]` thats your issue right there, not the `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

The method `signOrder` does not exist in `PreviewOrderViewController`

Comment: but it does exist, that's the weird part.  Something strange happened, going to kill what I got and try again.

Comment: that method does NOT exist, or theres a type somewhere, in that controller. Xcode doesnt lie. ;-).

Comment: could my problem be that I am trying to present another ModalViewController from withen a ModalViewController?

Comment: I am not sure what happened but I got it worked out somehow, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can present a Modal view FROM a Modal view.

Answer (score 0):

Still works for me, [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
SignatureViewController *targetController = [[SignatureViewController alloc] init];
[targetController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[targetController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentModalViewController:targetController animated:YES];
[targetController release];
```

By chance, what is your `SignatureViewController`? `UIViewController`?

Also, can you provide some crash output generated by Xcode?